# Garages and Gas Water Heater Vapor Elevation

Tags: water-heater

I just had a Rheem gas hot water heater installed in my garage. They put it on the floor and said that it doesn't have to be elevated as per code. Were they full of crap?

Comment: What is the floor made out of? One of the reasons to raise it is to create a fire proof barrier and provide a way to guide leaked water.

Comment: @ratchetfreak and to prevent explosions caused by floor level vapors https://www.ahit.com/news/Garage-Water-Heaters.htm

Comment: Does the new heater carry an FVIR (Flammable Vapor Ignition  Resistant) rating?

Answer (score 1):

According to the manufacturer's installation instructions, Rheem gas water heaters with FVIR can be installed directly on a garage floor, without the normal 18" stand. This allowance is only if local codes do not contradict:

[image]

Comment: Do all Rheem water heaters carry FVIR rating? I was unable to determine that without the model number.

Comment: I assume somebody still makes them without FVIR, as the 2016 Cal Plumbing Code still requires 18" elevation for garage installations *without* FVIR...